# Update Realm relationship with primary ids

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to update a Realm object's relationships by passing only the ids of the relationships?

If I have a `Library` class that has a `List<Books>` relationship and I wanted to merge two `Libraries` together, I would presume that could be done like:

```
let bookIds = (firstLibrary.books.toArray() + secondLibrary.books.toArray).map { $0.id }
```

Then I use ObjectMapper & SugarRecord:

```
let changes = ["books": bookIds]
Mapper<T>().map(changes, toObject: secondLibrary)
let realm = self.realm
realm.add(secondLibrary, update: true)
```

But the list of books doesn't get updated.
I assume this is because ObjectMapper doesn't know anything about primary ids and therefore trying to map them into an object doesn't do anything.

Does Realm have the capability to update via primary id? If it does, I'd gladly rewrite my persistence stack.

Comment: The code you've posted is a bit unclear. Your second snippet doesn't appear to refer to the object IDs at all, and makes reference to a number of different variables whose types are not obvious from the context. Can you provide more detail about what your models look like, and what you're trying to do with them?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: one workaround, which was discussed on [this Github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3594), is to modify the object creation code in the example as such:

```
let books = ["1", "2"].map { realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Book.self, key: $0) }
realm.create(Library.self, values: ["id": "4321", "books": books], update: true)
```

It's not possible to directly pass an list of primary key values as part of the value passed into the `create()` API to create a `Library`, and have Realm automatically create or update the `Book` objects associated with those primary keys.

Instead, this workaround first retrieves or creates the `Book` objects for each primary key value using `objectForPrimaryKey()`, and then creates the `Library` using those `Book` objects using `create()`.

Comment: Yeah. I just wanted to document the answer here in case anyone else on SO has the same question and finds this one.